# Oracle SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (ORA_ROWSCN) fails

Tags: oracle

Trying to run the following SQL which is basically an exact copy of an example I have seen on multiple sites, showing how to do this (I just change the tablename)

```
SELECT
SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) AS scn_time, ...
FROM
TABLE_ONE
WHERE
...;
```

But when I run it, it returns this error:

```
ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
08181. 00000 -  "specified number is not a valid system change number"
*Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
*Action:   use a valid scn.
```

What can I change to get this working? I am just looking to find the date/time a row was last updated.

Cheers in advance

K

Comment: According to documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953), ORA_ROWSCN is not guaranteed to reflect the last modified time for the specific row. "The only guarantee is that the value of ORA_ROWSCN ... is greater than the commit SCN of the transaction that last modified that row." If you really need to track last modified timestamp, then you should have a specific auditing solution in place (triggers, fine-grained auditing, etc.) to handle the requirement.

Comment: As far as your specific error goes, what value does ORA_ROWSCN actually return?

Answer (score 2):

[SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-BCB0C8EE-0E03-4A61-A41A-69975FAC1803)

> The association between an SCN and a timestamp when the SCN is
>   generated is remembered by the database for a **limited period of time**.
>   This period is the maximum of the auto-tuned undo retention period, if
>   the database runs in the Automatic Undo Management mode, and the
>   retention times of all flashback archives in the database, but no less
>   than 120 hours. The time for the association to become obsolete
>   elapses only when the database is open. **An error is returned if the
>   SCN specified for the argument to SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP is too old.**

Meaning the databases does not keep track of SCN-timestamp map forever and it is normal for `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` to fail for "too old" values.
With the SCN returned from ORA_ROWSCN, you can still try to find the period of the change from views such as `V$LOG_HISTORY` (`FIRST_CHANGE#`, `NEXT_CHANGE#`, `FIRST_TIME`, `NEXT_TIME`).

When the time of the last update is required, the actual value is typically maintained and stored in an extra column in the table. `ORA_ROWSCN` is not good enough for that.